# Django, updating from model

Tags: django, django-models, django-queryset

assume I have this little model:

```
class Deal(models.Model):
    purchases = models.IntegerField(default=0)#amount of purchases so far

    increase_purchases(self,to_add):
        self.update( purchases =self.purchases + to_add)
```

when I try to use this increase_purchases model from shell:

```
>>> x = Deal.objects.get(id=1)
>>> x.increase_purchases(4)
AttributeError: 'Deal' object has no attribute 'update'
```

How can I write a proper function to the model so that I can update the selected querys purchases as I want ?

Comment: You can't use `update` on an object, only to a queryset.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Based on your example and description, you probably want something like this:

```
class Deal(models.Model):        
    purchase_count = models.IntegerField(default=0)

    def purchase(self, quantity=1):
       self.purchase_count = self.purchase_count + quantity
```

I agree with Ignacio; modify the object and then save it.  So in the shell:

```
> great_deal = Deal.objects.get(id=1)
> great_deal.purchase(4)
> great_deal.save()
> # or w/o an explicite argument it will record a single purchase
> # great_deal.purchase()
```

Yes, I renamed things a little bit in the Deal model.  It just seemed more descriptive this way.

Answer (score 3):

Modify the appropriate fields then call `save()` on the instance.

Comment: but as far as I know save will be saving a new instance, while I want to update the existing one. regards

Comment: It will only create a new record if the PK is None or does not already exist in the database. Otherwise it will update the existing record with said PK.

Answer (score 1):

Or use the += expression for cleaner code:

```
class Deal(models.Model):        
    purchase_count = models.IntegerField(default=0)

    def purchase(self, quantity=1):
       self.purchase_count += quantity
```

Comment: Yeah, but how do you make this work in a concurrent situation where others may be doing the same?

Comment: It's better if you use F() here

Answer (score 1):

In Django 1.6.2. Encountered this behavior and used a "filter" then update works as expected. For example, Students.objects.select_for_update().filter(id=3).update(score = 10)

Just fyi: Unless you are handling transactions, modifying each field separately using save() might create data inconsistency in a multi-threaded environment. By the time threadA calls save() on a model, another threadB could have changed the model fields and saved. In which case threadA has to read the updated model and change.